# Pygame New Object Every Second

Tags: python, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

In pygame I need to make a flappy bird clone. I need to make recurring pipes so I want to do this by drawing new ones at the end of the screen every couple of seconds. I know there is a pygame.set_timer function but how do I implement this so that it counts in seconds and draws every couple of seconds

Comment: Have you tried to implement something already? You are getting downvotes because StackOverflow isn't a place for asking someone to write something for you without seeing your attempt(s).

Comment: At first, show your code. At second, you should use - pygame.time.Clock()

Comment: Yeah I know that but how do I get it to recognize that something is happening every two seconds

Comment: I'll sell you a computer with PyGame and a flappy bird clone installed. $15,000

Comment: Use some counter. Imagine, you have fps = 60, so in this game loop your counter must be added up to 60 - it means 1 second passed. That's it!

Answer (score -1):

If you posted your entire code I might be able to help you. Since you didn't post your code you should try something like this.

```
import time

while True:
    if (bird went past tube):
        return True
        ...create(...)
    else:
        return False
```